# Handling an exception where more or less than 4 characters is entered

Tags: java, input, exception, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a Mastermind program where it takes input for the guess, but I need to make sure that it only takes 4 characters of input. So if someone entered anything other than 4 characters, it would prompt for reentry. I know this isn't hard at all, I'm just drawing a blank and haven't been able to find an answer on here anywhere.

Comment: could you post some code that you've worked?

Comment: Try to write your own answer, and see if you can come up with something magical. If not, then we will help you with the magic.

Comment: Why do you even need an exception here?

Comment: The solution depends on the UI "framework". Do you capture user input on the console or with swing? If you want to forbid entering a fifth letter, then listen to key events (and count). BTW, a wrong user input is not an *exceptional state*, it is something that you simply have to expect. Don't use exceptions here.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to do it, one step at a time.

1. Get user input in your program. If it's standard input, one way to pull it is with [`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in), which is an [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).
2. Store the input in an intermediate variable. The type of this variable can be [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).
3. If needed, cast the value to a type which is the most relevant to your application's requirement. Before that check input for bad values like `null`.
4. Perform the logic on the input, which in your case is finding out whether the length of the input is 4.
5. Prompt again for input if the current one doesn't meet the requirement. One way to do it is to put your relevant code in a loop which terminates only when you get the right input.

And if that doesn't work, you're most welcome to ask again including code that shows your effort.